# Flutter : Exception caught by image resource service

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, flutter-android, google-maps

HTTP request failed, status Code: 403, when I try to call Map Api in flutter [Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl0pZ.png)
Anyone please help me out

Comment: You need to delete your image URGENTLY. You are publishing an api key to the world and others can make use of it at your cost.

Comment: Having said that, 403 code means permission denied so it could well be that the api key is invalid. Still, never publish api keys.

Answer (score 1):

The url shown in your screenshot returns the following message along with the 403 code:

> The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

You therefore have to do three things, in you code and on the Google cloud console:

1. Ensure that you trap and report any error message returned from the api in order to better understand the response code.
2. Cancel the api key that you have now published to the world and generate a new one for the Google maps api, in cloud console.
3. Enable billing on your project otherwise Google maps api will never work as it is a chargeable service.

Hope this helps. As I said, NEVER publish api keys nor store them on GitHub or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. If you are happy with the answer, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick. It motivates us to continue answering questions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say but error 403 means you don't have any access to that image from the server side.